# Java Application Program Error

Tags: java

i get the following error while running a packet sniffer code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ps.MainGUI.startbtnActionPerformed(MainGUI.java:399)
    at ps.MainGUI.access$000(MainGUI.java:26)
```

what could be the reason??the program code is give below :

```
 // TODO add your handling code here:
 startPacketbtn();
 ps.startUpdating();
```

and

```
public class MainGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public DefaultTableModel dtmPacket = new DefaultTableModel();
PSCaptor ps;
/** Creates new form MainGUI */
public MainGUI(int bufsize,boolean mode,int deviceno) {
    initComponents();
    System.out.println("HERE");
```

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointerException is? If not, what happened when you researched it?

Comment: The error says it: What's going on in line 26 in MainGUI.java ?

Comment: You never initialized ps. Change `PSCaptor ps;` to `PSCaptor ps = new PSCaptor();`